# Quels verbes conjuge-t-on avec être dans la langue courante ?

Tags: conjugaison, auxiliaires, niveau-de-langue, temps-composés

Il y a des sources qui disent que l'on doit conjuguer la verbe «passer» avec être au passé composé.

> Je suis passé par la mairie.

Mais il y en a d'autres qui disent que l'on peut utiliser aussi «avoir» dans la langue courante.

> J'ai passé par la mairie.

« Passer » est-il le seule verbe dans la liste qui nous permet les deux possibilités ? Ou est-ce que il y a des autres ? (avec divers niveaux de langue ?)

J'ai trouvé la liste ci-dessous mais peut-être que ce n'est pas complète.

> devenir revenir monter rester sortir passer venir arriver naître descendre entrer retourner tomber rentrer aller mourir partir + tous les verbes pronominaux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Emploi de l'auxiliaire aux temps composés

**Se conjuguent avec l'auxiliaire être :**

- les verbes pronominaux
- une liste de verbes qui sont des verbes de mouvement
  *aller, arriver, entrer (rentrer), partir (repartir), venir (revenir), tomber (retomber), venir (intervenir, parvenir, revenir, survenir)*

  ou d'état / changement d'état
  *décéder, devenir, mourir, naître, rester,*

**Se conjuguent avec avoir :**

- être et avoir
- tous les verbes transitifs
- la plupart des verbes intransitifs
- les verbes impersonnels

**Certains verbes peuvent utiliser *être* ou *avoir* :**

- selon qu'ils sont transitifs

  > Il a descendu l'escalier.
  >   Elle a rentré la voiture dans le garage.
  >   J'ai tombé la veste.<sup>1</sup>
- ou intransitifs

  > Elle est descendue à pied.
  >   Il est rentré dans la maison.
- ou selon leur sens

  > Elle est demeurée dix minutes sans bouger. (rester)
  >   Nous avons demeuré dans cette rue pendant vingt ans. (habiter)

  Grevisse<sup>2</sup> sur ce point signale aussi **échapper** qui s'utilise avec 
  *avoir* quand il a le sens de « n'être pas remarqué » :

  > Le véritable sens avait échappé à tous les traducteurs.

  souvent avec être quand il s'applique à ce qu'on dit par mégarde :

  > Je ne crois pas qu'il me soit échappé un seul trait par mégarde (Voltaire)

  et *être* ou avoir dans les autres cas :

  > Cela m'a échappé de la mémoire. /Cela m'est échappé de la mémoire

  Et **convenir** qui se conjugue avec *avoir* quand il a le sens de « plaire » et avec *être* quand il signifie « admettre » ou « tomber d'accord »

  > Nous sommes convenus de partir tous ensemble. (Villiers de l'Isle d'Adam)

  Mais il cite l'Office de la langue française (1938)  qui qualifie cette distinction de « subtile et franchement arbitraire »

  Grevisse signale aussi qu'un

  > certain nombre de verbes intransitifs ou pris intransitivement se conjuguent tantôt avec *avoir*, tantôt avec *être* : en général, ils prennent *avoir* quand on veut exprimer une action qui s'est passée à  l'époque dont on parle, et *être* quand on veut exprimer l'*état* résultant de l'action antérieurement accomplie. [...]
  >   J'ai passé par là en 1914 (É. Henriot)  [...]
  >   Je suis passée courageusement de Bretagne en Provence (Mme de Sévigné, Lettres)
  >   [...]

  Il signale aussi en note que beaucoup de ces verbes ne se conjuguent en fait qu'avec *avoir* et que quand ils prennent *être*, c'est que le participe passé est employé comme un simple adjectif :

  > Il est grandi. /  Il a grandi.

Pour en revenir à l'exemple donné dans la question, à savoir l'emploi de l'auxiliaire *avoir* avec **passer** utilisé de façon intransitive :

> J'ai passé par la mairie.

il se rattache au cas cité ci-dessus (action qui s'est passée à une certaine époque dont on parle), de nos jours ça sonne plutôt familier et vieillot mais on l'entend encore, tout comme :

> il a sorti ce matin.

Je suis tombée sur une [étude québécoise](http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/lfr_0023-8368_1977_num_34_1_4818) datant de 1977 et qui traite de l'alternance entre les auxiliaires *avoir* et *être* en français parlé à Montréal qui dit que :

> Dans la langue parlée, les formes du type *j'ai parti* existent toujours et
>   leur usage est devenu socialement marqué.

<sup>1. Je pense que cette expression est le seul cas d'emploi de tomber de façon transitive.</sup>
<sup>2. 10<sup>e</sup> édition, 1976, §656.</sup>

Comment: Je crois que la langue française a une de plus baroque grammaires qu'il existe.

Answer (score 1):

L'auxiliaire « avoir » est utilisé quand « passer » est transitif (accompagné d'un complément d'objet):

> - J'ai passé mon permis.
> - J'ai passé l'age.

L'auxiliaire « être » est utilisé quand « passer » est intransitif (pas de complément d'objet) :

> - Je suis passé au rouge.
> - Je suis passé par la mairie.

« <s>J'ai passé par la mairie</s> » est une "grosse" faute de français.

Comment: Dire que c'est une grosse faute n'est-il pas un peu exagéré ? C'est familier, certes,  mais la langue familière n'a-t-elle pas aussi droit de cité ? Le PO pose aussi la question du niveau de langue.

Comment: Je conviens volontiers que l'appréciation de la «grosseur» d'une faute est subjective et évolue dans le temps comme dans l'espace. Disons que je corrige mes enfants qui sont au cours préparatoire quand il leur arrive de faire cette faute et que je ne l'entends quasiment jamais d'adultes dont le français est la langue maternelle. D'autre part, familiarité et tournures fautives ne sont pas liées. Par exemple, le tutoiement est familier mais tout à fait correct.