# Full list of verbs conjugated with "être" and "avoir"

Tags: verbes, passé-composé, auxiliaires

I've found a partial list of verbs that are conjugated with *être* and *avoir*:

*Monter*, *Passer*, *Retourner*, *Sortir*, *Apparaître*.

Can someone add others and explain their differences?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can look  these up in any good dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common case of verbs that use either *être* or *avoir* is verbs that can be either intransitive or transitive. This is the case for *monter*, *passer*, *retourner*, *sortir*. The auxiliary is *avoir* when the verb is transitive (the auxiliary is always *avoir* for transitive verbs, because *être* + past participle is a passive, not a compound past). The auxiliary is *être* with an intransitive construction.

> Il ***est*** monté au troisième étage.   (*He went up to the third floor.*)
>   Il ***a*** monté l'escalier.   (*He climbed the stair.*)

There are other cases, generally more subtle. In the case of *apparaître*, to a first approximation, you can consider that the auxiliary is always *être*. There can be a distinction between the action of appearing (something became visible in the past → *avoir*) and the state of appearing (something looked a certain way in the past → *être*) but the use of *avoir* is disappearing in late 20th-early 21st century French.

See also [this much more detailed answer in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11277/quels-verbes-conjuge-t-on-avec-%C3%AAtre-dans-la-langue-courante/11285#11285).