# "Avoir monté" or "être monté"?

Tags: grammaire, auxiliaires

Could we use *être* as the auxiliary verb in the sentences below?

*La fourmi est monté le poteau au coin de la rue.*
*Elle est montée la colline pour prendre des photos.*
*Les saumons sont montés les cascades au printemps.*

Grammar books say that when the verb *monter* is transitive it should be used with *avoir*. Yet, I see some people use the verb *être* in similar sentences:

*Hier soir, Monsieur Picard est allé au cinéma à pied. Il **est monté** les escaliers jusqu'au centre-ville.*

Could I follow suit? Or are such sentences unacceptable?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25554/full-list-of-verbs-conjugated-with-%c3%aatre-and-avoir/25555

Comment: _Il est monté les escaliers jusqu'au centre-ville._ doesn't work.

Comment: but *Il est monté par les escalier jusqu'au centre ville* would.

Comment: @jlliagre Absolutely :-)

Comment: @Frank *Être* or *avoir*, that is the question! ;-)

Comment: *La fourmi est montée sur le poteau. Elle est montée sur la colline. Les saumons on remonté/gravi/franchi les cascades.*

Comment: Past particles agree with direct objects: *la colline qu'il a montée hier*. If you had an *être* verb with a direct object before the verb, would the past participle have to agree with both the subject and the direct object?

Comment: @PeterShor I think in general, it's either/or, there is no case of an agreement with both a subject and a direct object - that would be ill-defined anyway, in case they are of different number/gender. But I was never taught a rule to agree with both.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, that was my point. French manages to avoid this inconsistency by requiring verbs with direct objects to take the auxiliary *avoir*.

Comment: @PeterShor Very good observation!

Comment: @PeterShor Very honored to have you here by the way :-) It's big _goufre_ between QC and French ;-) I took Vazirani's class some years back which went over your algo.

Comment: @Frank: On second thought, maybe it doesn't avoid the inconsistency completely: *Elle s'est lavé les cheveux*.

Comment: @PeterShor And as a native at some distance from his education in French, those cases usually cause me to go verify which agreement I should do :-)

Comment: @PeterShor  Related: [Limits on the Use of the Indirect Object Pronoun to Indicate Possession](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43679/1893) .  Frank soyons sages, just like the saying goes in English, "France and Québec/Canada are two countries separated by same ocean."

Comment: Il a monté l'affaire lui-même. "L'affaire, il l'a montée lui-même". To go up the stairs as a direct object is: Il a monté les escaliers au lieu de prendre l'ascenseur. Versus: Il est monté à l'étage par les escaliers.

Answer (score 6):

As you said, using avoir or être as an auxiliary with the verb monter depends on the context of an object complement or COD, complément objet direct.  **With monter l'escalier, use avoir**.

> Julien a monté l’escalier quatre à quatre.

[BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23422/la-grammaire/le-verbe/auxiliaires/emploi-des-auxiliaires-avec-le-verbe-monter)

With the other sentences you give, there is also a direct object complement.  I would use avoir with all of them (unless you use a preposition like dans or à).

- Les saumons ont monté les cascades.

Without a direct object, especially when the subject is a person, use être :

> Harold est monté se reposer quelques minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, be careful that "monter" isn't an exact equivalent of "to walk up". Most of the time it means "to mount" and it can have a sexual meaning.

The rule is hard to grasp, but here are ways to help you get it right.

You can use *avoir monté* if the direct object is something that is being climbed upon. So the sentence:

> X a monté Y.

Should have the same meaning at the passive voice:

> Y est monté* par X. (you have to make the agreement with Y, so you'd write *la fourmi est monté**e***.)

For example:

> J'ai monté un cheval. (I mounted a horse)

> Un cheval a été monté par moi. (A horse was mounted by me)

But:

> Je suis monté sur un cheval. (I climbed onto a horse)

Because you can't say:

> Sur un cheval a été monté par moi. (Onto a horse was climbed by me?)

Likewise:

> La fourmi est montée sur le poteau. (The ant climbed on the post)

or

> La fourmi a monté le poteau.

This last one, depending on the context, could mean

- "the ant mounted the post" (maybe it expected the post to start moving like a horse)
- "the ant assembled the post" (it received a lego set of a post and built it up)
- "the ant brought the post in a higher place" (it was needed upstairs for some reason)
- "the ant crossed the post to move upward" (the ant path goes through climbing up this post)

Same goes for "la colline", "les cascades" and "les escaliers":

> Elle est montée sur la colline. / Elle a monté la colline

> Les saumons sont montés par les cascades. / Les saumons ont monté les cascades.

> Il est monté par les escaliers. / Il a monté les escaliers.

Comment: The ant climbed *up* the post. However, for stairs we say go up or climbed the stairs. The salmon jumped up the waterfalls. Or leapt up the waterfalls. They went or swam upstream by jumping over the waterfalls. Il a monté une affaire. He **set up**. The boy [better than ant here] took the post upstairs. The boy set up the post, too.

Comment: *Monter à cheval* est figé pour *riding a horse.*

Comment: *La fourmi est monté**e** sur le poteau.* / *Elle est monté**e** sur la colline.*

Comment: @livresque *Monter à cheval* et *monter un cheval* existent tous deux avec des sens et des usages distincts.