# Y a-t-il une raison de choisir « avoir » plutôt que « être + convenu » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, auxiliaires

Cela semble-t-il étrange pour un locuteur natif français : « Marie est venue, comme nous en étions convenus » ?
Pourquoi *avoir* vs *être* serait utilisé avec *convenir* ici et en général ? Y a-t-il une différence subtile ? Y a-t-il une raison spécifique lorsque *être* est utilisé ? Peut-être que l'auteur veut obscurcir ou dispenser de culpabilité le sujet pour une raison quelconque ? Il n'y a aucune raison dans le contexte pour que ce soit le cas ici.

Comment: Il semble que j'avais [déjà répondu à la question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11285/358) et que j'avais oublié, est-ce vraiment un doublon ?

Comment: @Laure Je ne crois pas. L'autre est seulement un commentaire, pas une réponse complète.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selon le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/convenir) :

> La règle traditionnelle est d'employer ***convenir*** :
>
> - avec l'auxiliaire *être* dans le sens de *« se mettre d'accord, reconnaître »* ;
> - avec l'auxiliaire *avoir* dans le sens de *« être approprié »* ;
>
> mais cette règle n'est pas toujours suivie, et l'usage tend à employer *avoir* comme seul auxiliaire, dans les 2 cas.

Comment: Dans ce cas, l'être est le choix approprié et Albert Camus était grammaticalement correct

Answer (score 6):

*Convenir* peut se conjuguer avec être ou avoir.

L'[Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/nous-avons-convenu-que)  dit:

> Le verbe *convenir*, quand il signifie « correspondre aux besoins, aux goûts, aux aptitudes de quelqu’un », se construit avec l’auxiliaire *avoir* ; on dit *Jusque-là* cette fonction m’a *convenu*. Mais quand *convenir* signifie « décider, arrêter d’un commun accord », il se construit avec l’auxiliaire *être*. Employer *avoir* dans ce cas est une faute qu’il faut éviter.

Grevisse, §6 58, remarque 3, 10<sup>e</sup> édition :

> Cette distinction est « subtile et franchement arbitraire », dit l’Office de la langue française (cf. revue Université, févr. 1938, p. 127). — Il n’est pas douteux, en effet, que le bon usage actuel n’autorise l’emploi de l’auxiliaire *avoir* avec *convenir* (déjà chez J.-J. Rousseau, Romain : cf Littré) dans le cas où la règle officielle demande l’auxiliaire *être* : Nous avons convenus que je ne t'écrirais qu'au bout d'un certain temps (Stendhal, Corr. t II, p. 123).

Donc Camus suit l'Académie Française mais Grevisse donne de très nombreux exemples de « grands » écrivains qui ne suivent pas cette « règle ».

Ce sujet est source de discussions :

- [Convenir : être ou avoir convenu ?](http://www.langue-fr.net/Convenir-etre-ou-avoir-convenu) sur le site *langue-fr.net*
- Intervention du CSA à ce sujet : [Être et avoir convenu](http://www.csa.fr/Etudes-et-publications/Les-dossiers-d-actualite/Langue-francaise-Quelques-difficultes/Etre-et-avoir-convenu)
- [Convenir (à, de, que)](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/convenir-a-de-que-a4540464) sur *Parler français*.
- Et bien sûr les fins observateurs et défenseurs de la langue française que sont les Québécois ont leur mot à dire, voir l'article [convenir / convenu](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=91fqEHykp64Y.html) sur Termium+.

Comment: Ça n'invalide pas votre dernière remarque, mais le [_Juridictionnaire_](http://www.cttj.ca/?page_id=208) est une œuvre, que d'aucuns qualifient d'exceptionnelle, de l'Université de Moncton (Jacques Picotte), au Nouveau-Brunswick (Néo-Brunswickois(e)). _Termium+_ dispose de contenus originaux et a aussi un rôle d'agrégateur de contenu. Merci !